# Multiple interaction controls on a single computer

Tags: operating-systems, io

I wonder if there is a way to interact with a single computer using two interaction controls.For example,two people must be able to interact with two different application simultaneously on the same computer. Assume there are two keyboards and mouses attached to the computer.

Comment: In Linux, you can start as many X servers as you like, configuring each instance to use a separate videoadapter, keyboard and mouse.

Comment: unless this is a server this is a very bad idea, as it will be very difficult for both users to work effectively, unless you have multiple screens and use virtual work-environments on separate screens. What's the purpose of needing 2 users to interact on the same machine, at the same time?